# MonoGame 2D PixelShader not working

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, shader, monogame

I am trying to implement a PixelShader in Monogame.

The shader (for now) should just take a Texture and give it back unmanipulated.

```
sampler MyTex : register(s0);

float4 PixelShaderFunction( float2 coords: TEXCOORD0 ) : COLOR0
{
    float4 Color = tex2D(MyTex, coords);
    return Color;
}

technique tech
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

my Monogame implementations looks like this:

in LoadContent:

```
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("surge");
GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = texture;
effect = Content.Load<Effect>("sha");
```

and in the Draw Method:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Aquamarine);

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend,null, null, null, effect, null);
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(150, 150), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

But it shows nothing. Changing the BlendState to Opaque gives me a black Rectangle where the texture should be. I also tried changing To other Sortmodes and BlendStates without success. I just cannot seem to find the Problem.
Any answer that helps solving the problem or is decreasing the self-hatred I have because of this is highly appreciated!

EDIT: Is the problem that resource binding (registering) changed throughout the shader model versions?!
Someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Steffen i have tried this code for Greyscale Effect

```
texture Texture;
sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state
 {
   Texture = <Texture>;
 };
```

// This data comes from the sprite batch vertex shader

```
struct VertexShaderOutput
{
  float4 Position : TEXCOORD0;
  float4 Color : COLOR0;
  float2 TextureCordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};
```

// Our pixel shader

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
   float4 color = tex2D(TextureSampler, input.TextureCordinate);

   float value = 0.299*color.r +  0.587*color.g + 0.114*color.b;
   color.r = value;
   color.g = value;
   color.b = value;
   color.a = 1.0f;

   return color;
}
```

// Compile our shader

```
technique Technique1
{
  pass Pass1
  {
    PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
  }
}
```

or you may try this [link](http://joshuasmyth.maglevstudios.com/post/XNA-and-Monogame-Introduction-to-Pixel-Shaders1) and [this](https://gmjosack.github.io/posts/my-first-2d-pixel-shaders-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with that shaderfile I cannot even compile. MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets(90,5): error MSB3073:[..] ended with code 1

Answer (score 0):

Manoj's code was correct you just have to change the:

```
float4 Position : TEXCOORD0;
```

to

```
float4 Position : PS_POSITION;
```

and it will work just fine!

You might want to also change the compiler to:

```
PixelShader = compile PS_SHADERMODEL PixelShaderFunction();
```